# How to group together iOS elements so they can be operated on as a single element

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-animation

I have 3 UI elements in my iOS app that I would like to treat as a single entity when animating.

There's a a UIImageView on top of which sits a UILabelView and UIActivityIndicatorView. Is there a way to group these things together and animate the group without having to animate each one independently?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, put them in a container `UIView` (it will be theirs `superview`) and animate it.

```
UIView* containerView = // alloc-init
[containerView addSubview:aSubview]; // repeat for the other views you have
```